# ResourceBundle can't find BaseName gradle project java

Tags: java, automation, cucumber, bdd

I am trying to read fields from a file.properties with ResourcesBundle, here's the code:

```
public static final ResourceBundle QUERY_EXCEL = ResourceBundle.getBundle("ConsultaExcel"); 
String query=QueryManager.QUERY_EXCEL.getString("SQL.SELECT.consultarDatos");
```

When I run my project it throws an exception

> Can't find bundle for base name ConsultaExcel, locale es_CO

the properties file is in Resource folder that is inside of src/main/resources

Comment: The properties file must be named `ConsultaExcel.properties`.  Its base name must match the ResourceBundle name it represents.

Comment: i changed it and it keeps throwing the same error

Comment: "Resource folder inside src/main/resources". Do you mean "src/main/resources/Resource/ConsultaExcel.properties" ? It should be "src/main/resources/ConsultaExcel.properties"

Comment: the path is src/main/resources/ConsultaExcel.properties and it doesnt work, i tried with a new project just doing a main class with that code and it works, so i dont know what could be happening

Comment: can somebody help  me please

Comment: Have the same problem. Does anybody have a solution

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I could solve this by reinstalling IntelliJ IDEA and installing the plugins by defects